# How to create referral link like launchrock in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to create referral links like.

```
www.abc.com/1234
www.abc.com/4345
```

Where number are the referral codes which will be unique for every user. I am sure this can be done in ruby on rails with some routes configuration. Means where the request will be routed. Which controller? which action? How to get value of unique code.

ps: [launchrock](http://launchrock.com) is using referral links like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this structure with route matching but you would need to have the referral codes match a specific pattern. If, for example, they matched the format of 3 letters followed by three numbers, you could put the following your routes file:

```
match '/:referrer_id' => 'app#index', :constraints => {:referrer_id => /[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/}
```

The reference to app#index should be changed to the controller in which you handle referrals and you can access the referrer_id through params[:referrer_id].

Certainly have a look at the link referenced in Markus' answer for suggestions on how to generate the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I have a link in my bookmarks with regard to token generation: http://blog.logeek.fr/2009/7/2/creating-small-unique-tokens-in-ruby

In your application you will need to store the individual tokens in the user table. Controller and action are up to you and for the routes you could go with something like www.abc.com/referral?123456.

```
routes.rb
match "/referral/:ref" => "controller#action"

access in controller with:
params[:ref]
```